# Can "no need to run" mean "no need to hurry/rush"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm a Brazilian lyricist and I have this doubt regarding the phrase "no need to run". Here in Brazil, people understand "running" also as "doing something fast". That said, I'm writing lyrics in English (for American listeners) and I was about to write the following lines:

> "Let's fade out the end of lovemaking/
>   slowly through the hours, no need to run."

Translating it to Brazilian Portuguese, the intended meaning ("doing it slowly, without the need to hurry") works just fine, but I wonder if it actually works for a native speaker of English. I'm worried that people won't get the right meaning and understand it as "escaping".

Can anyone shed a light on this question for me?

Comment: "Run" would imply leaving in this context. "Rush" would imply taking time.

Comment: No, “run” would not convey the meaning you want to express, which is sort of “take it easy”.

Comment: I see. Yes, I thought so. I was hoping that having the word "slowly" there would help with the meaning I wanted to express. So maybe I should use the word "hurry" instead, "No need to hurry"... but then I would lose the rhyme ("run" was the rhyme for "one").
What if I want to say "slowly through the hours of rising sun.", does it work or do i need to put a "the" between "of" and "rising"?

Answer (score -1):

Here, **to run** means **to run off** (to leave soon or suddenly). From the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/run-off), definition 1:

> **run off**
>   to leave somewhere or someone suddenly:
>   *You can't run off (home) now, just when I need you!*